# Where to look up design pattern of symfony?

Tags: php, design-patterns, symfony1

The official website seems only provided some tutorial on how to use:

http://www.symfony-project.org

But I want to know why the directories should be setup like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This guide details the reasoning behind the Symfony file structure: http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_2/02-Exploring-Symfony-s-Code

Answer (score 4):

Symfony is based on a lot of patterns, this blog post highlights a few of them:
http://obvioushints.blogspot.com/2008/12/symfony-design-patterns.html

Basically, it's a [model-view-controller (MVC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller) framework and the directories are setup like that only to organize the numerous configuration and PHP files that are created during a normal, structured project. Of course, you'd need to be a little bit more specific on what makes you curious about the directory structure but if you go through the [documentation](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/04), you'll find interesting facts about how your project will be divided. The directory structure is not necessarily related to a specific design pattern itself (the code is) but probably more related to just getting your files organized.

Anyway, Symfony is a PHP framework like many others, and just by going through generic design patterns using classic books such as [Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321127420) or websites about [PHP patterns recipes](http://www.fluffycat.com/PHP-Design-Patterns/), [popular patterns](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-designptrns/) or [extensive lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern_(computer_science)#Classification_and_list), you should get a good idea on the general structure.